# cardinality of recursive/r.e/not r.e languages?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, undecidability, sets, semi-decidability

I was just looking into properties of languages and wondered about the cardinality of them

- are all recursive languages countable or can they also be uncountable
  (can u have a recursive language which is uncountable?)
- can r.e languages be countable and uncountable?
  (can u have a r.e but not recursive language which is uncountable?)
- are all non r.e languages uncountable?
  (can u have a non r.e language which is countable?)

an explanation would be nice but i am not necessarily looking for a proof. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about the cardinality of the sets $R$, $RE$, and $\overline{RE}$, as [the set of all words in a language is always countable](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53187/is-there-any-uncountable-turing-decidable-language).

- $R$ (the family of recursive langauges) is countable, because there the set of Turing Machines is countable, and there is at least one TM for each $R$ language.
- $RE$ is countable, by the same logic, since there is a TM semi-deciding each $RE$ language.
- The set of non-$RE$ languages, $\overline{RE}$, is not countable, then by process of elimination. The set of all languages, $\mathcal{L}$, over an alphabet $\Sigma$ is $\mathcal{P}(\Sigma^*)$ i.e. the powerset of the set of all words. 
  This set is uncountable, since $\Sigma^*$ is countable, and the powerset of a set always has higher cardinality.

  $\mathcal{L} = RE \cup \overline{RE}$, and $RE$ and its complement are disjoint, so since $RE$ is a countable subset, there must be an uncountable number of words in $\overline{RE}$.

Comment: i think i phrased the question slightly wrong. what i was essentially asking was:can u have a recursive language which is uncountable? can u have a  r.e but not recursive language which is uncountable? can u have a non r.e language which is countable? ill edit the question

Comment: In that case, this is a duplicate of the question I linked. All languages over finite alphabets are countable.